# AngularJS / Ionic routing using $stateProvider - controller is not reloading the second time a state is called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, url-routing, hybrid-mobile-app

### Original Question

I'm developing a mobile app using the Ionic Framework and AngularJS and I am having issues with controllers not reloading once they have been initialised.

One of the state transitions (from `'app.postbox-details'` to `'app.audit-questions'`) should pass a parameter to the `'app.audit-questions'` controller but this controller does not update itself with the new parameter because it isn't reloading.

Code Example

*app.js file - config*

```
angular.module('sf-maintenance', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])           
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $stateProvider
       .state('home', {
           url: '/home',
           templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
           controller: 'HomeCtrl',
       })
       .state('app', { //app state being the side-menu
           url: '/app',
           abstract: true, //means that this state will never be activated directly, users will always go to a child state instead.
           templateUrl: 'templates/side-menu.html',
           controller: 'MenuCtrl'
       })       
       .state('app.postbox-details', {
           url: '/postbox-details',
           views: {
               'menuContent': {
                   templateUrl: 'templates/postbox-details.html',
                   controller: 'PostboxDetailsCtrl'
               }
           }
       })
    .state('app.audit-questions', {
        url: '/audit-questions/:postboxGuid',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/audit-questions.html',
                controller: 'AuditCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

*controller.js file (left out the code that isn't relevant)*

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])    
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope) {
})    
.controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope) {
})    
.controller('PostboxDetailsCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, $cordovaBarcodeScanner, $state, DataService) {

    $scope.postboxGuid = DataService.getNewGUID();
    //Rest of the controller functions are below
})    
.controller('AuditCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $stateParams, DataService) {

    $scope.auditDetails = {
        postboxGuid: $stateParams.postboxGuid
    };    
});
```

*View - navigation code*

The view code to perform the navigations all use `<a>` tags:

- From the home view to the postbox-details view: `<a class="button button-block button-dark icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/app/postbox-details">New inspection</a>`
- From the postbox-details view to audit-questions view: `<a class="button button-block button-dark icon-right ion-chevron-right" ng-click="saveFormData()"
         ng-href="#/app/audit-questions/{{postboxGuid}}">New audit</a>`

So does anybody know how to get controllers to reload once it has been initialised or if I am going about this problem the wrong way could you guide me to a method that will work?

---

### Updated Information

I recently saw a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896079/reload-true-works-only-once) and the response by @Radim Köhler pointed to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991990/ui-router-not-reloading-controller) which provides good information on why it may not be a good idea to use `cache:false` on a view because of performance.

I thought I would share this because in some situations you may benefit more performance-wise by using one of [Ionic's built-in view life cycle events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)  to run code without having to disable the view from being cached.

Comment: use `ui-sref` instead of ng-href

Comment: for first anchor use `ui-sref="app.postbox-details"` & for second anchor use `ui-sref="app.audit-questions({postboxGuid: postboxGuid})"` instead of their respective href

Comment: Most at times issues related to controllers are much of typos and injection error; check what you inject into each controller and use the browser's console to debug the errors

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Views are standard cached in ionic. The caching can configured in the view or stateprovider.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: Thanks Toxus this has fixed the prolem :) I completely overlooked how Ionic handled state changes within `ion-nav-view`

Comment: I think this problem exists only with latest version of Ionic. I have an app with old ionic version where i have cache=false and controllers still work fine.