# ui.router not reloading controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an application using Ionic Framework and there are multiple views. The route names are **app.view1** and **app.view2**. I transition to the next view form the controller using `$state.go("app.view2")` and when I click back the controller of app.view1 is not executed again which is very important in my application.

Please tell me how to make the controller be executed whenever I route to it.

Comment: Can you provide code where you define states?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ionic caches views for faster performance. It uses feature of `ng-router`.

> Ionic will cache a maximum of 10 views, and not only can this be configured, but apps can also explicitly state which views should and should not be cached.

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

There are multiple ways to address this issue.

**Option 1**

If you want controller to execute everytime the view is shown, you can disable cache for that particular route.

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

or

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ...
</ion-view>
```

**Option 2**

You can disable cache for all views. And even control the number of views. I don't know if this could be useful to you or not.

```
$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
```

**Option 3**

My favourite. You can use [`$ionicView.enter`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) event. This guarantees that the code that needs to be executed when the view is should would be executed. So you can differentiate code should be executed one time and every time. I guess this would have positive impact on performance.

**Usage**

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
  // Coding
});
```

Good luck and happy coding!