# What is the difference between $ionicView.enter and cache:false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm developing a view that need call multiples methods of a webservice every time the view is opened, should i use `$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){...})` or `cache:false` ?

What is the real difference between each one?

Comment: Why not just have the controller for the view call those methods on activation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I really enjoyed this Q & A:

#### [ui.router not reloading controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30991990/1679310)

Where the [Bipin Bhandari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30993488/1679310) nicely summarizes the options we have with ionic caching mechanism

1. avoid caching by  `cache: false`,
2. disable caching with `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0)`;
3. or keep caching as is, and let controller be executed only once ... while doing some smart stuff during these [View LifeCycle and Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

So, with caching in place, controller will be executed just once:

> Views are cached to improve performance. When a view is navigated away from, its element is left in the DOM, and its scope is disconnected from the $watch cycle. When navigating to a view that is already cached, its scope is reconnected, and the existing element, which was left in the DOM, becomes active again.

We can hook on these events... to do some "always stuff" with this controller

Comment: Thanks Radim, your answer is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Great to see that, really ;) Enjoy awesome ionic framework!

Answer (score 9):

`$ionicView.enter` is an event that is broadcasted each time the selected view is activated.

`cache:false` means that the page will never be cached, and is therefore, reloaded completely each time.

I personnaly try to avoid using cache false as it as bad performances but has side effects as your controller won't be initialised again when you are back on it.

Instead, when I enter a view, I user `$ionicView.enter` or `$ionicView.afterEnter` to trigger several actions for page to completly finished the loading.

Comment: Thanks Aorfevre, simple and helpful answer