# In AngularJS with views (routing) why controllers are executed only going forward?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I have an Ionic project (which use AngularJS) with views. Routing is like:

```
.state('menu.play', {
  url: '/play/:audioIndex',
  views: {
    'side-part': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/play.html',
      controller: 'playCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

On the controller I get 'audioIndex' parameter and set it to `$rootScope`, `$scope` and show it on the console

```
.controller('playCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.viewsAudioIndex = $stateParams.audioIndex;
    $scope.audioIndex = $stateParams.audioIndex;

    console.log("stateParams.audioIndex: " + $stateParams.audioIndex);
})
```

I start at `http://localhost:8100/#/menu/play/0`.
My next audio button is like:

```
<a href="#/menu/play/{{audioIndex + 1}}">Next</a>
```

I click it three times, then on the console I have

```
stateParams.audioIndex: 0
stateParams.audioIndex: 1
stateParams.audioIndex: 2
stateParams.audioIndex: 3
```

That is fine, the issue is when I click on *back* button;

```
<a href="#/menu/play/{{audioIndex- 1}}">Back</a>
```

Console does not print anything, **is like controller is not being called**.

I checked in chrome dev tool (AngularJS tab) and $rootScope does not change when I go *back*. Views routing works fine, no problems with that.

Recap, if I start at `menu/play/0` and I do

1. Click next
2. Click next
3. Click next
4. Click back
5. Click back
6. Click back
7. Click next
8. Click next
9. Click next

I get on the console

```
stateParams.audioIndex: 0
stateParams.audioIndex: 1
stateParams.audioIndex: 2
stateParams.audioIndex: 3
stateParams.audioIndex: 1
stateParams.audioIndex: 2
stateParams.audioIndex: 3
```

Any idea why? I saw that when I go back Scopes are destroyed, but that doesn't explain `$rootScope` is not being updated.

Comment: You should check the caching in ionic http://stackoverflow.com/a/31074503/1679310

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Radim said I had to disable the cache:

```
angular.module('my-app.config', [])
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally angular routing have to be done using ui-sref. Haven't tested your case, but you'll still need to change your links to avoid other bugs:

```
<a ui-sref="menu.play({audioIndex: {{audioIndex + 1}}})">Next</a>
<a ui-sref="menu.play({audioIndex: {{audioIndex - 1}}})">Back</a>
```