# localstorage sometimes cannot load the values in Ionic App

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, local-storage, hybrid-mobile-app, ngcordova

Hi I'm using localStorage in my hybrid app developed using Ionic framework. Everything works fine, but recently we've noticed that if I keep my app in background for a longer period,like 5-6 hours, and while I re-open the app, it looses its values in the localStorage. But if I force quit my app and re-open it, it works fine, and then it gets all the values in the localStorage... Quite strange for me, as this only happens in IOS, and Android works absolutely fine...

CODE:

```
function initState() {

            if (userService.token().token) {
                $q.all([
                    panelService.panelGET(),
                    userService.userGET(),
                    authenticationService.sessionGET()
                ]).then(function (data) {
                    console.log('InitState: ', data);
                    if (data[0]) {
                        checkTouchId();
                    } else {
                        next(data);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if (localStorageService.get('welcome')) {
                    window.location.hash = 'signin';
                } else {
                    window.location.hash = 'welcome';
                    localStorageService.set('welcome', true);
                }
            }
        }
```

where initState() is called in the OnPlatformReady event...

userService.token().token is getting token key from the localStorage...

Comment: Which type of localstorage you used ?session storage or another

Comment: No, its not session storage. Its localStorage... I mean the other one...

Comment: Post your code that processing the localstorage

Comment: Please check the updated info...

Comment: It may be related to the problem explained by this blogger: http://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/ and reported here: http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-localstorage-persistence/20004/11

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with cacheing .Cache your views using  `$ionicView.enter` like this way

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //call your initState() function here 
});
```

For more information about `$ionicView.enter` [Refer this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073765/what-is-the-difference-between-ionicview-enter-and-cachefalse)

Comment: No, it is not a problem with the view, it is a problem with the localStorage, that it once do not load the data but on re-opening the app, it loads the data stored in it...