# angular-ui-router resolve is fired but value is not updated when 'beforeEnter'

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, state

I inject `testResolve` in `DoctorHomeCtrl`,
and when it loaded,the value of testResolve is right.
After going to another page and go back , the function is fired but the value of testResolve is not updated.

```
    controller: 'DoctorHomeCtrl',
    resolve:{
      testResolve:function ($q, $timeout) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () {
          defer.resolve(new Date());
        }, 100);
        return defer.promise;
      }
    }
.....
.controller('DoctorHomeCtrl', [....,'testResolve',
function (....,testResolve) {
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
    console.log('testResolve');
    console.log(testResolve);
  });
```

Comment: If you put a console.log inside the testResolve() function, does it fire on coming back into the page?

Comment: yes,it fired and logged the updated value.

Comment: PS:in ngRoute,it's absolutly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour:

> ...After going to another page and go back , the function is fired but the value of testResolve is not updated...

Is correct. Simply, Ionic does some custom, out of UI-Router performance optimization... caching. And that means, that it breaks expected UI-Router behaviour.. because:

> whenever is **view** init, and its `controller` is instantiated... the **`resolve`** is triggered.

But here.. we are provided with cached controller... not being re-init.

Solution? Maybe as discussed here

#### [What is the difference between $ionicView.enter and cache:false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31073765/1679310)

avoid caching... or just do the resolve stuff inside of the onEnter event...

Comment: thanks.And "cached controller also trigger the resolve" is right or not?

Comment: Well, cached means.. it was already initiated. And only during init (creation) is resolve evaluated, to properly pass data into constructor function... So, cached will never re-trigger... hope it helps a bit... good luck with UI-Router and ionic

Comment: but the resolve is also fired when goback.i think it shouldn't been fired.

Comment: It really depends, if that will trigger the cached controller, or if that will in fact destroy old view... and create new. Also.. there is a cache size, which releases older cached items.. but in general.. do not use resolve in this scenarios with Ionic. its caching will be unpredictable... helps?

Comment: got it.Anyway i plan to handle the data only in 'loaded'.thanks for anwser.