# angular-js: Multiple instances of controller being created in ui-router

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I have noticed that, whenever a `$state.go()` is applied to a state with parameter(s) in AngularJS UI-Router, a new instance of the HTML content [for that view] is created each time. Not only the HTML content, but also the controller are being created as many times as newer params are appearing on the `$stateParams` after calling `$state.go()` in the program later on.

How do I stop new instances of HTML content and controller to stop appearing, while still passing the params to the `$stateParams`? I want to use the same controller, same scope and same HTML content for any data that `$stateParams` holds.  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: how do u come to know that multiple instance are created ? can you create a fiddle ?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "instance of the HTML content", or what your exact scenario is, but I think what you see is completely expected. Controllers are not singletons like services are. Each time a view with a controller is displayed, a new scope instance and a new controller is created. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @ngLover, multiple instances of HTML codes are being created. Suppose I have a code like `<div ui-view>content</div>`,  multiple instances go like `<div ui-view>content</div><div ui-view>content</div>`. This applies to anything that the UI-router creates. So you can use any fiddle you like, with a state containing a parameter in its url.

Comment: @JBNizet how do I make controllers singletons?

Comment: @DamodarDahal, create a controller at a higher level (e.g. at an app-level), so it won't change with each state, if this is what you need

Comment: You don't. Just accept the fact they're not, and shouldn't be. If you have a specific problem to solve, then ask a question about it.

Comment: @NewDev that might be helpful. Thank you. But, how about the problem of HTML code being duplicated over and over for different `$stateParams`?

Comment: @DamodarDahal, you need to show *some* code. It's pointless to speculate otherwise

Comment: never mind. I found another method to cover it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, it is possible. Disable caching.

This is done in various ways. One of the ways would be to be disable caching while defining the states. Eg:

```
$stateProvider.state("home",
    {
        url:'/home',
        cache:false,
    }
```

Adapted from [ui.router not reloading controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991990/ui-router-not-reloading-controller/30993488#30993488)