# reload: true works only once

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am trying to pass parameters from one view to another in my anulgar/ionic app.

in the `volCompute` view ($stateParams is declared):

```
if ($stateParams.modelLine){
    console.log('receiving', $stateParams.modelLine.id, $stateParams.modelLine.modelStrict)
    $scope.data.chosenModel = $stateParams.modelLine.modelStrict;
}
```

in the `compare`view:

```
$state.go('app.volCompute', { modelLine: test[0] }, {reload: true});
```

but it works only one time, if I go back and forth between the two views the code in `volCompute` is not run.
It seems like the `reload: true` is only executed once.

Can you help please ?

Comment: Ionic uses cache for the templates. If you want to disable it then you can put `cache: false` in the `app.volCompute` state definition.

Answer (score 1):

There are few more details how to understand ionic caches

- [What is the difference between $ionicView.enter and cache:false](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31073765/1679310)
- [ui.router not reloading controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30991990/1679310)

And I would suggest to use the event hook here `$ionicView.enter` or `$ionicView.afterEnter`

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
  // Coding
});
```

there is the [link to doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/)

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file:

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

Or inidividually in an `<ion-view>` tag:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false">
    ...
</ion-view>
```