# Ionic - AngularJS - How do you go about refreshing the view state on click.

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
        <a href="#/assessments/{{assessment.id}}">
            <div class="item item-divider">
                <h2>{{assessment.test.name}}</h2>
                <p>{{assessment.test.items.length}} questions</p>
            </div>
            <div class="item item-text-wrap item-icon-right">
                {{assessment.test.introduction}}
                <i class="icon-next icon"></i>
            </div>
        </a>
```

I need to pull through the id for each anchor that is created in a ng-repeat and then before it gets to the next state I need it to refresh the state instead of just loading the data. Is there a way to not do this in the controller?

Comment: Maybe this question might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087683/angularjs-ionic-routing-using-stateprovider-controller-is-not-reloading-the

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<a ui-sref="assessments({id: assessment.id, reload: true})">
  <div class="item item-divider">
    <h2>{{assessment.test.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{assessment.test.items.length}} questions</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-text-wrap item-icon-right">
    {{assessment.test.introduction}}
    <i class="icon-next icon"></i>
  </div>
</a>
```

Then have this in your stateProvider:

```
.state('assessments', {
  url: '/assessments/:id',
  templateUrl: 'assessments.html',
  controller: 'assessmentsController'
});
```